# ¿Como llamar nombres en php desde una Base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Buenas tardes amigos tengo este codigo en HTML (es solo una parte de todo el codigo) e igual cuento con una base de datos, quisiera saber como poder que en donde dice "Monica", "uzziel", "Andres" pudiera traer los nombres que tengo registrados en mi base de datos.

A si tengo mi cuadro por el momento: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFHz4.jpg

Mi codigo.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
   <th>Docente</th>
   <th>1</th>
   <th>2</th>
   <th>3</th>
   <th>4</th>
   <th>5</th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td>Monica</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestam"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestam"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestam"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestam"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestam"></td>
 </tr>   


      <tr>
   <td>Uzziel</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestau"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestau"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestau"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestau"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestau"></td>
 </tr> 


       <tr>
   <td>Andres</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestaA"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestaA"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestaA"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestaA"></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="respuestaA"></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Hice hace poco un ejemplo de construcción de una tabla con datos obtenidos de la base de datos. Puedes **[ver el código aquí](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tcy5-b093)** y probar el resultado pulsando donde dice **`Run F9`**. Puse comentarios en el código explicando los conceptos básicos, pensando en casos como el tuyo. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado general, por favor aclara: Que base de datos usas? Ya pudiste establecer la conexión con la base de datos? Ya tienes algún código en PHP?  Ya has investigado en otros lugares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Este script te puede servir.

Cree una tabla con estos campos (para mi prueba):

```
create table docente (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL , 
respuesta integer(1), 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

insert into docente values ( "", "Monica", 3),
  ("", "Uzziel",5), ("", "Andres", 4);
```

Archivo php

```html
   <?php
    // crear la conexion
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "Password", "NombreDB");

/* verificar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

// consultar la tabla
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM docente";

?>


<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
   <th>Docente</th>
   <th>1</th>
   <th>2</th>
   <th>3</th>
   <th>4</th>
   <th>5</th>
 </tr>
 
<?php
 // recorrer la tabla docente
 if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {
   while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
   ?>
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $fila["nombre"] ?></td>
    <?php for ( $i=1;$i<=5; $i++){
     if( $i ==  $fila["respuesta"] ){ 
              ?>
     <td><input type="radio" 
                name="<?php echo $fila["nombre"]; ?>"  
       value="<?php echo $i; ?>"
       checked ></td> 
     <?php     
     }else{  
     ?>
     
     <td><input type="radio" 
                name="<?php echo $fila["nombre"]; ?>"  
       value="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
    <?php 
        }
    }
    ?>
  </tr>   

<?php

}
}
   ?> 
   </table>
```